# Jquery Rounded Tabs Cross Browser (slight problem)

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

Ive been trying to create some rounded tabs without images which work in all browsers, ive taken various code from different places and nearly got it working, the only problem is that the tab background color doesnt stay white when the tab is active.  Ive been trying to fix this for hours with no luck.  It uses csspie for the rounded corners,  you can view an example on the page here :

http://www.usedcar.co.uk/testtabs.html

Any help would be appreciated.  I havent managed to find a decent example of jquery tabs without images.

Comment: Are you having this problem with all browsers or certain ones?

Comment: All of my most recent large clients (Fortune 500 types) have been more than happy with Jquery UI tabs that gracefully degrade back to square for those luddites on IE6/7.  It's a LOT cleaner solution than using images, and a lot less overhead than hacking for the two browsers that really don't matter in the grand scheme of things.  And really, what's the loss if a few users see square instead of round?  I've actually had to point out the difference to a few users who didn't notice.  Just sayin'

Comment: Why not use jQuery UI's [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)? You can use the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to style them however you like and they're cross-browser compatible and degrade nicely (as @bpeterson76 says).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the extra curly brace it's bugging your code out...

```
    behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);}
}
```

EDIT: here are the demos...

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/j6sF5/1

Not Working: http://jsfiddle.net/j6sF5/2/ (extra curly brace)

Answer (score 1):

You can either fix this in the click event, or in css(preferably in css).
click:

```
 $('.selected a').css('background-color', 'white');
```

or in css, something like

```
.selected a{background-color: white;}
```

in your css you have:

```
.tabBox .tabs .selected a {
    background: #FFF;
}
```

EDIT(Your css behavior 'PIE.htc' is causing you problems):
At the end of on click add:

```
$(".tabBox .tabs li").click(function() {
    $(".tabBox .tabs li").removeClass("selected"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("selected"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tabBox .content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).show();
//add-->
    **$(".tabBox .tabs").find('li[class!=selected]').find('a').css('background-color', '#EEE');
    $(this).find('a').css('background-color', '#FFF');**

    return false;
});**strong text**
```

Comment: Hi,  Ive changed this and got it to work fine in firefox and chrome, but in IE7, each time you click a new tab, the previous tab stays white and doesnt go back to the grey color.

Comment: switch the order of your a:active and your .selected a in your css

Comment: Ive made a few changes, the new one is at the page below : http://www.usedcar.co.uk/testtabs2.html    , the problem is that in IE8, each time you click on a new tab, the background of the previous tabs stays white instead of going back to grey.

Comment: Use jquery, your htc file is overriding your css styles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version: http://jsbin.com/afina3/8/edit

Made two changes. The first was to move the selected style above the .tabBox .tabs a style:

```
.tabBox .tabs .selected a {
    background: #FFF;
}

.tabBox .tabs a {
    float: left;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    background: #EEE;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    border-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    color: #000;
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);}
}
```

Then in the jQuery code I added this line to add the selected style to the  tag of the tab:

```
$(this).find('a').addClass("selected"); //add selected style to the link of this tab
```

Comment: Ive made a few changes, the new one is at the page below : http://www.usedcar.co.uk/testtabs2.html    , the problem is that in IE8, each time you click on a new tab, the background of the previous tabs stays white instead of going back to grey.

Comment: Try adding this line to the jQuery to remove the selected class from the links: 
$(".tabBox .tabs li a").removeClass("selected"); //Remove any "active" class

Answer (score 0):

```
.tabBox .tabs a:hover,
.tabBox .tabs a:active,
.tabBox .tabs .selected a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

Should fix it :)